# Why is it advantageous to solve for $x$ in a $u$-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

In Spivak's *Calculus*, in the chapter "Integration in elementary terms" while discussing $u$-substitutions, he comments that "most substitution problems are much easier if one resorts to this trick of expressing $x$ in terms of $u$".

What is it about doing this that makes it easier? It seems no information is gained by putting it in terms of $x$. It just seems like extra work. I understand the value of it and I use it often, and I realize this is what happens when doing trig substitutions, but is there a solid reason that this can make the integral easier?

Comment: In an indefinite integral, your function is an explicit function of $x$. So if you write $x=h(u)$, you can compute $dx$ directly, plug in $h(u)$ for $x$ directly.

Comment: It depends.  Wikipedia gives the examples $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2} x \cos(x^2+1) \,dx $ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\; dx$ and suggests different approaches for each

Comment: Specifically with the example of $$\int x\cos(x^2+1)dx$$ a $u$ substitution with $u=f(x)$ is the best since the derived result of $u=x^2+1$ is $du=2x\text dx$ and this form is directly available for substitution.  It might be statistically interesting to find out how many integrals "work out more easily" with the two different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an indefinite integral, your function is an explicit function of $x$. So if you write $x=h(u)$, you can compute $dx$ directly, plug in $h(u)$ for $x$ directly.  The substitution process is then purely mechanical.